# How to install yafaray for blender 2.77+?

Tags: rendering, add-on, installation, external-applications

I'd like to install/enable yafaray renderer on Blender 2.77a. Every time I try to enable the Add-on, it returns an error. I tried reinstalling Blender, nothing.

[image: error]

Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: Download YafaRay.v3.0.0-beta.build.for.Blender.2.77a That works.

Answer (score 1):

The current YafaRay Release v3.1.0-beta works with Blender v2.77a and v2.78.

You can download the builds for Linux, Windows and MacOSX from [www.yafaray.org](http://www.yafaray.org/)